# Store location of PHP array value

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a way to store the location of a php array value for use later so for example it might look like this.

```
CreateArrayShortcut($BIGARRAY["lev1"]["lev2"]["lev3"]["lev4"]["lev5"], $shortcut);

$shortcut = "newvalue";

echo $BIGARRAY["lev1"]["lev2"]["lev3"]["lev4"]["lev5"];
// Outputs newvalue

echo $shortcut;
// Outputs newvalue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)?

```
$shortcut = &$BIGARRY[blah blah blah blah]['lev5'];
            ^---
```